# Upload blob directly from client to container

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Can anyone please advise me if it is possible to directly upload a file to a blob container without routing it through my web server? I'm thinking some sort of client-side JS/jQuery script or a 3rd party upload module that streams the file directly to the blob container.

With Amazon S3 I used a component called [Flajaxian Direct Uploader](http://www.flajaxian.com/flajaxian.com/DirectAmazonUploader1.0Help.html) to achieve this.

I have the need to upload zip files to an Azure blob container that are 50 mb - 200 mb in size and routing via the web server is slower and consumes additional bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  This can be achieved by having the client contact your web server and ask for a Shared Access Signature with (w)rite only access and limited expiry.  Your client can then use the simple REST API to upload the blob.  The trick here is that if your blob is bigger than 64mb, you must use use the PUT block and PUT block list option.  The latter is not as straightforward for a Javascript client.  If your client can use curl, it works well.

Reference:

[PUT Blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx)

[PUT Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135726.aspx)

[PUT Block list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179467.aspx)

Comment: Do take a look at this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670649/upload-file-to-azure-blob-storage-directly-from-browser/15673384#15673384.