# Azure encoding job fails

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am uploading a video via rest to our azure media server but the encoding job fails with the following exception:

```
    null
ErrorProcessingTask : Azure Media Encoder could not load the preset Preset.xml on source tom2.mp4:File type isn't supported.
```

I can see that it states the filetype is no supported, but if I upload it manually there is no problem.

This is how I am posting the video

```
     var uploadLocatorId = asset["Id"];

            var uploadurl = asset["BaseUri"].ToString() + "/tom2.mp4" + asset["ContentAccessComponent"].ToString();

            var formcontent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\VideoFiles\tom2.mp4");
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            Int32 blobLength = fileBytes.Length;
            stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        //    stream.Close();

            var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            //    here you can specify boundary if you need---^
            var mp4ieContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
            mp4ieContent.Headers.ContentType =
                MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
            mp4ieContent.Headers.ContentLength = blobLength;

            var memory = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            var streamcontent = new StreamContent(memory);
            formcontent.Add(streamcontent, "tom2", "tom2.mp4");
           // formcontent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            var date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var container = AssetID.ToString();
            container = container.Replace("nb:cid:UUID:", "asset-");


            client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2014-02-14");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", date);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(type);

            result = await client.PutAsync(uploadurl, formcontent);
```

The file is present on the azure server, but cannot be played.

Can anyone point me in any direction, please

Answer (score 1):

The [following topic](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-rest-upload-files/) describes what steps you need to take when using REST to create an asset and upload a file into a blob (you can use any method to upload your file).

The general steps are:

- Create an asset (that generates a blob container).
- Get a SAS url.
- Create an asset file (with the same name as your physical file, for example, Video.mp4).
- Upload your physical file (Video.mp4) to the SAS url. For more information about uploading a file, see 
  [Upload file to Azure Blob Storage directly from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670649/upload-file-to-azure-blob-storage-directly-from-browser)
- Update the asset file with the size and other information as needed.
- Schedule an encoding job.
- Publish the asset by creating an On-Demand locator.

Alternatively, you can create an asset file after you upload blobs. You would then enumerate the container and create corresponding AssetFiles.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were missing some metadata on your video asset. Here is code you could use to create Asset, and upload files as AssetFiles for that particular asset. Then you run encoding preset on the video asset.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj129584.aspx

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan

Comment: Hi Mingfei, thank you for the responds. I have been staring a lot at that documentation for the last week or so and have not been able to produce a working example using the rest api. Furthermore I have not been able to find any sample project showing the use of the rest api. Therefore I am abandoning this approach.  I have lost.