# SAVE and GET PDF to/from Microsoft Azure Blob Storage container using JsPdf Library in Javascript

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, jspdf

I want to save the pdf to Azure Blob storage container and retrieve it. How can I do this?
    **I tried this to save the PDF to Local Drive but I want to store this directly to BLOB storage without saving it on Local Drive.**

```
  let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
doc.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    doc.save('html.pdf');
});

**Can any suggest me a solution?
How to send the PDF content to Azure Blob storage?**
```

Comment: Have you looked at the node.js SDK for Azure Storage? This SDK provides functions for connecting to Azure Storage, uploading content to blobs, downloading content from blobs, and more. There's also a JavaScript client library available. I'd suggest checking out the SDK, then posting follow-up questions with specific issues you run into once you get the SDK set up.

Comment: Yes check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670649/upload-file-to-azure-blob-storage-directly-from-browser